# Fetch Directories as per updated timestamp in a directory in Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I need to list directories based on the time stamp of the files modified inside the directory in ascending order. I have the below code which gets me all the directories. But, I needed directories in ascending order of timestamp.

I know we can use `ls -ltr` but using awk on `ls -ltr` can give me unexpected results when I need only specific columns of output. If someone can help me, please let me know

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $baseDir = "<My base dir>";

opendir my $dh, $baseDir
  or die "$0: opendir: $!";

my @dirs = grep {-d "$baseDir/$_" && ! /^\.{1,2}$/ && ! /^\.[a-zA-Z]*/}        readdir($dh);
print "DIRs is @dirs\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort based on directory modification time relative to script start-up time [`-M`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

```
my @dirs = 
  map $_->[0],
  sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
  map [ $_, -M "$baseDir/$_" ], 
  grep {-d "$baseDir/$_" && ! /^\.{1,2}$/ && ! /^\.[a-zA-Z]*/}
  readdir($dh);
```

Comment: `@dirs` contains no data after running the above line.

Comment: @ArunShankar comment all `map/sort` lines; perhaps your filter doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Thanks it works.. The directory I had mentioned did not have the directories and it kept failing.. Thanks for the help !!!